# How to scrape website-elements that are using same tags and classes?

Tags: python, html, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

*Scraping website-elements that are using same keys and classes & challenges with jumping in loop using Python's BeautifulSoup*

I have been looking everywhere for a solution, talked with a software engineer and my python-professor regarding this, which couldn’t help. This is my first post so please bear with me:

I try to scrape a website using BeautifulSoup to call the elements I want to extract. The main challenge is that the website I try to scrape from, are using the same classes and keys in multiple occations with different elements (In this example: tag = `span` classes = `text-nowrap`).
This means my output from the functions defining the elements I want are printing the same (first HTML-line, which has a tag=`span` and class = `text-nowrap` from above).

In this instance, I thought I might need an additional parameter in the list.find helping it distinguish as some elements consists of special elements like date-format, m², DKK/m² and so forth? Or is there any other ways?

Furthermore, I seem to have a problem regarding jumping when creating the loop. Printing the soup.find_all class-parameter (in this case, “Container mb-5”), I get all the information I want (unfiltered).However, as soon as I try to create a loop defining the functions of the elements I want printed, the loop only loops once (from the top) giving me one example instead of multiple lines of data. Syntax seems correct.

Below is my Python-code:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
pip install lxml
pip install requests

from bs4
import BeautifulSoup
from lxml
import etree
import requests

from csv
import writer

url = "https://www.boliga.dk/salg/resultater?searchTab=1&sort=date-d&saleType=1&propertyType=1,3&salesDateMin=2015"
page = requests.get(url)
print(page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
lists = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "container mb-5")


for list in lists:
  resitype = list.find('span', class_ = "text").text
  address = list.find('a', class_ = "text-primary font-weight-bolder text-left").text
  price = list.find('span', class_ = "text-nowrap").text.replace('\xa0kr.', "")
  salesdate = list.find('span', class_ = "text-nowrap")
  rooms = list.find('td', class_ = "table-col d-print-table-cell text-center")
  sqm = list.find('span', class_ = "text-nowrap")
  sqmprice = list.find('span', class_ = "text-nowrap mt-1").text
  salestype = list.find('span', class_ = "text-nowrap mt-1").text
  buildingyear = list.find('span __ngcontent-boliga-app-c182', class_ = "table-col d-print-table-cell text-center")
  procent = list.find('a', class_ = "price-reduced ng-star-inserted")

info = [resitype, address, price, salesdate, rooms, sqm, sqmprice, salestype, buildingyear, procent]

print(info)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the releveant data into Pandas dataframe you can do:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.boliga.dk/salg/resultater?searchTab=1&sort=date-d&saleType=1&propertyType=1,3&salesDateMin=2015"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")


all_data = []
for row in soup.select("tr"):
    tds = row.select("td")

    resitype = tds[0].p.get_text(strip=True)
    address = tds[0].a.get_text(strip=True, separator=",")
    price = tds[1].get_text(strip=True)
    salesdate = tds[2].get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
    sqm = tds[3].get_text(strip=True, separator=",").split(",")[0]
    sqmprice = tds[3].get_text(strip=True, separator=",").split(",")[-1]
    rooms = tds[4].get_text(strip=True)
    buildingyear = tds[5].get_text(strip=True)
    procent = tds[6].get_text(strip=True)

    all_data.append(
        {
            "resitype": resitype,
            "address": address,
            "price": price,
            "salesdate": salesdate,
            "sqm": sqm,
            "sqmprice": sqmprice,
            "rooms": rooms,
            "buildingyear": buildingyear,
            "procent": procent,
        }
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         resitype                                           address           price             salesdate     sqm       sqmprice rooms buildingyear procent
0   Ejerlejlighed                      Storegade 31A, st,4780 Stege   2.200.000 kr.  14-09-2022 Alm. Salg   95 m²   23.158 kr/m²     3         1890        
1   Ejerlejlighed                       Storegade 31A, 1,4780 Stege   2.200.000 kr.  14-09-2022 Alm. Salg   99 m²   22.222 kr/m²     3         1890        
2   Ejerlejlighed                          Storegade 31B,4780 Stege   2.200.000 kr.  14-09-2022 Alm. Salg   48 m²   45.833 kr/m²     2         1890        
3           Villa                         Hybenvænget 6,5800 Nyborg   1.795.000 kr.  13-09-2022 Alm. Salg   96 m²   18.698 kr/m²     4         1971        
4           Villa                     Grønnevang 306,3250 Gilleleje   2.595.000 kr.  12-09-2022 Alm. Salg  105 m²   24.714 kr/m²     4         1987        
5           Villa                          Teglvej 10,9800 Hjørring     860.000 kr.  08-09-2022 Alm. Salg  139 m²    6.187 kr/m²     4         1954        
6   Ejerlejlighed            Benløseparken 177, 2. tv,4100 Ringsted   1.500.000 kr.  07-09-2022 Alm. Salg  103 m²   14.563 kr/m²     4         1980     -3%
7   Ejerlejlighed                Lundevej 36, st. 4,4400 Kalundborg   1.450.000 kr.  07-09-2022 Alm. Salg  134 m²   10.821 kr/m²     2         1957     -3%
8   Ejerlejlighed          Lundtoftegade 93, 4. th,2200 København N   3.970.000 kr.  07-09-2022 Alm. Salg   70 m²   56.714 kr/m²     3         1930     -1%
9   Ejerlejlighed           Øresundsvej 112, 3. th,2300 København S   2.650.000 kr.  07-09-2022 Alm. Salg   62 m²   42.742 kr/m²     2         1932     -5%
10  Ejerlejlighed             Åboulevard 60, 1. tv,2200 København N   4.200.000 kr.  07-09-2022 Alm. Salg  104 m²   40.385 kr/m²     3         1903     -7%
11  Ejerlejlighed             Ålandsgade 18, 3. tv,2300 København S   2.025.000 kr.  07-09-2022 Alm. Salg   41 m²   49.390 kr/m²     1         1940     -8%
12          Villa                       Tømmerupvej 209,2791 Dragør   3.445.000 kr.  07-09-2022 Alm. Salg  201 m²   17.139 kr/m²     7         1928        
13          Villa                   Lillebjergvej 35,3390 Hundested   3.795.000 kr.  07-09-2022 Alm. Salg  182 m²   20.852 kr/m²     6         1979        
14          Villa                             Ageren 19,4652 Hårlev   2.760.000 kr.  07-09-2022 Alm. Salg  174 m²   15.862 kr/m²     5         1973     -3%
15          Villa                      Holbækvej 44,4400 Kalundborg   2.095.000 kr.  07-09-2022 Alm. Salg  176 m²   11.903 kr/m²     5         1921        
16          Villa                            Lokesvej 5,4220 Korsør   1.100.000 kr.  07-09-2022 Alm. Salg  222 m²    4.955 kr/m²     8         1971        
17          Villa                         Britaniavej 3,8500 Grenaa     486.500 kr.  07-09-2022 Alm. Salg  134 m²    3.631 kr/m²     4         1978        
18          Villa                           Assensvej 15,5853 Ørbæk     750.000 kr.  07-09-2022 Alm. Salg  159 m²    4.717 kr/m²     8         1930        
19          Villa             Ålsgårde Stationsvej 19,3140 Ålsgårde   1.700.000 kr.  07-09-2022 Alm. Salg  114 m²   14.912 kr/m²     5         1965        
20          Villa                        Platanvej 15,4000 Roskilde   6.300.000 kr.  07-09-2022 Alm. Salg  146 m²   43.151 kr/m²     7         1947        
21          Villa                       Saugstedvang 5,5600 Faaborg     900.000 kr.  07-09-2022 Alm. Salg  157 m²    5.732 kr/m²     3         1976        
22          Villa                      Thorsvænget 1,3000 Helsingør   3.850.000 kr.  07-09-2022 Alm. Salg  122 m²   31.557 kr/m²     5         1905        
23  Ejerlejlighed        Frederikssundsvej 408, 2. tv,2700 Brønshøj   2.045.000 kr.  06-09-2022 Alm. Salg   63 m²   32.460 kr/m²     3         1954     -2%
24  Ejerlejlighed                      Ørebakken 22B,3000 Helsingør   1.245.000 kr.  06-09-2022 Alm. Salg  217 m²    5.737 kr/m²     6         1897        
25  Ejerlejlighed  Henrik Ibsens Vej 10, 4. th,1813 Frederiksberg C   6.220.000 kr.  06-09-2022 Alm. Salg   84 m²   74.048 kr/m²     3         1899        
26  Ejerlejlighed              Messinavej 9, 1. tv,2300 København S   2.445.000 kr.  06-09-2022 Alm. Salg   55 m²   44.455 kr/m²     2         1937     -2%
27  Ejerlejlighed               Blåbærhaven 12, 1. mf,2980 Kokkedal     600.000 kr.  06-09-2022 Alm. Salg   48 m²   12.500 kr/m²     2         1973        
28  Ejerlejlighed                  Folehaven 114, st. th,2500 Valby   1.850.000 kr.  06-09-2022 Alm. Salg   58 m²   31.897 kr/m²     2         1937     -7%
29  Ejerlejlighed                     Bøgelundsvej 67B,6920 Videbæk     620.000 kr.  06-09-2022 Alm. Salg   77 m²    8.052 kr/m²     2         1978     -5%
30          Villa                        Skolestien 4,3150 Hellebæk   7.500.000 kr.  06-09-2022 Alm. Salg  218 m²   34.404 kr/m²     5         1995     -5%
31          Villa                         Møllevangen 9,8450 Hammel   2.550.000 kr.  06-09-2022 Alm. Salg  179 m²   14.246 kr/m²     5         1973        
32          Villa                     Ålholmparken 95,3400 Hillerød   2.864.500 kr.  06-09-2022 Alm. Salg  184 m²   15.568 kr/m²     7         1970        
33          Villa                         Engmarkvej 11,7620 Lemvig     250.000 kr.  06-09-2022 Alm. Salg  151 m²    1.656 kr/m²     3         1905        
34          Villa                  Dronningensgade 19,4100 Ringsted   2.750.000 kr.  06-09-2022 Alm. Salg   95 m²   28.947 kr/m²     2         1938        
35          Villa                     Ndr Dragørvej 173,2791 Dragør   2.875.000 kr.  06-09-2022 Alm. Salg   76 m²   37.829 kr/m²     4         1915        
36          Villa                               Sdr Alle 9,9760 Vrå     430.000 kr.  06-09-2022 Alm. Salg  122 m²    3.525 kr/m²     3         1927    -13%
37  Ejerlejlighed         Borups Allé 235B, 2. th,2400 København NV   2.450.000 kr.  05-09-2022 Alm. Salg   66 m²   37.121 kr/m²     2         1921     -2%
38  Ejerlejlighed     Johan Kellers Vej 49, 1. th,2450 København SV   1.285.000 kr.  05-09-2022 Alm. Salg   59 m²   21.780 kr/m²     2         1936        
39  Ejerlejlighed             Middelfartvej 54, 2. th,5200 Odense V   1.635.000 kr.  05-09-2022 Alm. Salg   94 m²   17.394 kr/m²     4         1956        
40  Ejerlejlighed                 Bagerstræde 9, 3,1617 København V   9.000.000 kr.  05-09-2022 Alm. Salg  154 m²   58.442 kr/m²     5         1908     -5%
41  Ejerlejlighed              Willemoesgade 45, 4,2100 København Ø  14.500.000 kr.  05-09-2022 Alm. Salg  188 m²   77.128 kr/m²     5         1889        
42  Ejerlejlighed          Brandholms Alle 28B, st. th,2610 Rødovre     820.000 kr.  05-09-2022 Alm. Salg   66 m²   12.424 kr/m²     3         1961        
43  Ejerlejlighed                        Roret 119,3070 Snekkersten   3.695.000 kr.  05-09-2022 Alm. Salg  112 m²   32.991 kr/m²     3         2002        
44  Ejerlejlighed               Bjergbygade 6, st. tv,4200 Slagelse  13.150.000 kr.  05-09-2022 Alm. Salg  113 m²  116.372 kr/m²     4         1960        
45  Ejerlejlighed                Bjergbygade 6, 1. th,4200 Slagelse  13.150.000 kr.  05-09-2022 Alm. Salg  113 m²  116.372 kr/m²     4         1960        
46  Ejerlejlighed                Bjergbygade 6, 3. tv,4200 Slagelse  13.150.000 kr.  05-09-2022 Alm. Salg  102 m²  128.922 kr/m²     4         1960        
47  Ejerlejlighed                Bjergbygade 6, 3. th,4200 Slagelse  13.150.000 kr.  05-09-2022 Alm. Salg   98 m²  134.184 kr/m²     4         1960        
48  Ejerlejlighed                Bjergbygade 6, 2. tv,4200 Slagelse  13.150.000 kr.  05-09-2022 Alm. Salg  125 m²  105.200 kr/m²     5         1960        
49  Ejerlejlighed                Bjergbygade 6, 1. tv,4200 Slagelse  13.150.000 kr.  05-09-2022 Alm. Salg  116 m²  113.362 kr/m²     4         1960
```

Comment: Dear Andrej, thank you so much for the help and your contribution to your discussion. 

However, it seems like when exporting all_data to an existing excel-file or CSV.file for an example, it is not giving me the scraped information, but the whole HTML-code despite using all_data, which is nicely placed in the Dataframe. What to do about that?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** *Avoid using `python` reserved terms ([`keywords`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)), this could have unwanted effects on the results of your code.*

1. Select your elements more specific - I would recommend to avoid unspecific `classes`
   and like to go with [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors), more stetic identifiers and HTLM structure.
2. You could also assign values to multiple variables in one go.
3. Put `info` into your `for-loop` to call it immediately in each iteration.

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = "https://www.boliga.dk/salg/resultater?searchTab=1&sort=date-d&saleType=1&propertyType=1,3&salesDateMin=2015"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline="") as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(['resitype', 'address', 'price', 'salesdate', 'rooms', 'sqm', 'sqmprice', 'salestype', 'buildingyear', 'procent'])
    for row in soup.select('table tr'):
        resitype = row.select_one('app-tooltip+span').text
        address = row.a.text
        price = row.select_one('td:nth-of-type(2)').text.split()[0]
        salesdate,salestype = row.select_one('td:nth-of-type(3)').stripped_strings
        rooms = row.select_one('td:nth-of-type(5)').text
        sqm,sqmprice = row.select_one('td:nth-of-type(4)').stripped_strings
        buildingyear = row.select_one('td:nth-of-type(6)').text
        procent = row.select_one('td:nth-of-type(7)').text
        info = [resitype, address, price, salesdate, rooms, sqm, sqmprice, salestype, buildingyear, procent]
        print(info)
        #write your result to csv
        w.writerow(info)
```

##### Output

```
resitype,address,price,salesdate,rooms,sqm,sqmprice,salestype,buildingyear,procent
Ejerlejlighed," Storegade 31A, st 4780 Stege ",2.200.000,14-09-2022, 3 ,95 m²,23.158 kr/m²,Alm. Salg, 1890 ,
Ejerlejlighed," Storegade 31A, 1 4780 Stege ",2.200.000,14-09-2022, 3 ,99 m²,22.222 kr/m²,Alm. Salg, 1890 ,
Ejerlejlighed, Storegade 31B 4780 Stege ,2.200.000,14-09-2022, 2 ,48 m²,45.833 kr/m²,Alm. Salg, 1890 ,
Villa, Hybenvænget 6 5800 Nyborg ,1.795.000,13-09-2022, 4 ,96 m²,18.698 kr/m²,Alm. Salg, 1971 ,
Villa, Grønnevang 306 3250 Gilleleje ,2.595.000,12-09-2022, 4 ,105 m²,24.714 kr/m²,Alm. Salg, 1987 ,
Villa, Teglvej 10 9800 Hjørring ,860.000,08-09-2022, 4 ,139 m²,6.187 kr/m²,Alm. Salg, 1954 ,
Ejerlejlighed," Benløseparken 177, 2. tv 4100 Ringsted ",1.500.000,07-09-2022, 4 ,103 m²,14.563 kr/m²,Alm. Salg, 1980 , -3% 
Ejerlejlighed," Lundevej 36, st. 4 4400 Kalundborg ",1.450.000,07-09-2022, 2 ,134 m²,10.821 kr/m²,Alm. Salg, 1957 , -3% 
...
```

Comment: Dear HedgeHog, Thank you for being so nice to help me in this regard! regarding using .stripped.strings I actually want to rinse these objects from " kr/m²" in sqmprice and "  m²" in sqm. I have been battling with using the .replace-parameter. Glancing though the forums, I do not see any clear answer to this specific examples where two of the same objects has the same keys and class + I want to remove some characters from one (sqmprice) and remove som other in the other (sqm). How can I proceed?